# List of controllers empty with cgroup v2

Tags: linux, cgroup

I am trying to learn how cgroups v2 work. I did this:

```
mount -t cgroup2 none /mnt/cgroup2
```

That gave me a list of objects in `/mnt/cgroup2`

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# ls -la /mnt/cgroup2/
total 4
dr-xr-xr-x  5 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep  2 16:05 ..
-r--r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 cgroup.controllers
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 cgroup.max.depth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 cgroup.max.descendants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 cgroup.stat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:07 cgroup.subtree_control
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 cgroup.threads
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Sep  2 16:04 init.scope
drwxr-xr-x 59 root root    0 Sep  2 16:00 system.slice
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Sep  2 15:59 user.slice
```

However, the file `/mnt/cgroup2/cgroup.controllers` is empty. I thought it should have the list of controllers, is that not correct? Reading docs here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cgroup controllers can only be mounted in one hierarchy (v1 or v2). If you have a controller mounted on a legacy v1 hierarchy, then it won't show up in the cgroup2 hiearchy. This limitation is documented in [cgroup-v2 - Mounting](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#mounting) as well as the `cgroups(7)` manual page:

> It is not possible to mount the same controller against multiple 
>   cgroup hierarchies.  For example, it is not possible to mount both 
>   the cpu and cpuacct controllers against one hierarchy, and to mount 
>   the cpu controller alone against another hierarchy.  It is possible 
>   to create multiple mount points with exactly the same set of 
>   comounted controllers.  However, in this case all that results is 
>   multiple mount points providing a view of the same hierarchy.
>
> Note that on many systems, the v1 controllers are automatically 
>   mounted under /sys/fs/cgroup; in particular, systemd(1) automatically 
>   creates such mount points.

To avoid this legacy behavior, boot with the `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` option. This option might become the default in the future according to the [NEWS entry for systemd v233](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/NEWS#L1365).

To illustrate, these cgroup filesystems are mounted on an Arch Linux system using systemd 239:

```
tmpfs    on  /sys/fs/cgroup                   type  tmpfs    (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2  on  /sys/fs/cgroup/unified           type  cgroup2  (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd           type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct       type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset            type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio  type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/memory            type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/pids              type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio             type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma              type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer           type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event        type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/devices           type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb           type  cgroup   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
```

The read-only `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/cgroup.controllers` file is initially empty. After unmounting the `cpu` controller (`cpu,cpuacct`), the `cpu` controller becomes available. Unfortunately, not all controllers (like `memory`) become available even after unmounting all v1 `cgroup` filesystems. The ones that are available are:

```
cpu io rdma
```

When booting with `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1`, no v1 filesystems are mounted:

```
cgroup2  on  /sys/fs/cgroup           type  cgroup2  (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
```

And now some more controllers become available:

```
cpu io memory pids rdma
```

Comment: Hi @Lekensteyn, in your example is there a way to make the `memory` controller available without rebooting the node?

Comment: You may also want to append `cgroup_no_v1=all` as a boot option. I had to. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635645/346609 for details.