# Where can I find up-to-date documentation for the croupv1 memory resource controller?

Tags: linux, cgroup, documentation

Anyone know where can I find some up-to-date documentation for the cgroupv1 memory resource controller?

The docs.kernel.org [page](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html) about the cgroupv1 memory resource controller contains the note at the top:

```
This document is hopelessly outdated and it asks for a 
complete rewrite. It still contains a useful information 
so we are keeping it here but make sure to check the 
current code if you need a deeper understanding.
```

I want to get a sense of what this controller does and how to use this specific controller without delving into the linux source code.

Comment: Why not the cgroup2 controller?

Comment: The reason I'd prefer to use cgroupv1 over cgroupv2 is because for my use-case I don't want to have to restart the nodes in order to spin up the cgroupv2 controllers, after disabling cgroupv1 in the bootloader settings (by setting the 'cgroup_no_v1' kernel parameter, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html).

Comment: What happens if you try to mount cgroupv2 though and use that instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem I face is the problem described here:

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/929080/list-of-controllers-empty-with-cgroup-v2/931180#931180

Comment: In short, I want to make the `memory` controller available without rebooting the node.